# Web application working on iis7 but not on local machine

Tags: vb.net, web-services, ssl-certificate, client-certificates

I have my VB.NET web application successfully built and compiled on ISS7 server but on the local machine when compiling through Visual studion 2013 it is 
returning "System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: The system cannot find the file specified." error. 
Not sure what is happening but throws an error at `Dim cert As New X509Certificate2(certFile, certFilePassword,X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet)`

Below is the code where I am trying to use a certificate that is installed on my local machine.

```
Sub LoginED(ByVal token As String)
Try
'We need the ED user ID
lblEDUserID.Text = GetEDUserID().ToString()

'Track user login
InsertLogin(txtEDUsername.Text, True)

'Set login cookies for ED users            
If lblEDUserID.Text = "0" Then
lblEDLoginStatus.Text = "You have entered an incorrect login. Please try again."
Else

Dim certFile As String = "VIP_Cert.pfx"
Dim certFilePassword As String = "password"

Dim cert As New X509Certificate2(certFile, certFilePassword,X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet)
Dim vipSoapInterfaceQueryServiceCert As New WebReference.QueryService

'Dim fs As FileStream = File.Open(certFile, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite)
'Dim filesize As Long = fs.Length
'Dim buffer(filesize) As Byte
'fs.Read(buffer, 0, filesize)

'byte[] buffer = new byte[fs.Length];
'int count = fs.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
'fs.Close()

lblEDLoginStatus.Text = "Activation  "
vipSoapInterfaceQueryServiceCert.ClientCertificates.Add(cert)

Dim vipSoapInterfaceService As New WebReference.GetCredentialInfoRequestType()
vipSoapInterfaceService.credentialId = "SMR23324543"
vipSoapInterfaceService.credentialType = WebReference.CredentialTypeEnum.STANDARD_OTP
vipSoapInterfaceService.requestId = "ABCD"

Dim vipSoapInterfaceResponse As New WebReference.GetCredentialInfoResponseType()

vipSoapInterfaceResponse = vipSoapInterfaceQueryServiceCert.getCredentialInfo(vipSoapInterfaceService)
lblEDLoginStatus.Text = "WebService Response: " + vipSoapInterfaceResponse.credentialId + ", Status:" + vipSoapInterfaceResponse.credentialStatus

End If
Finally
```

What I have tried so far:
1) Tried to specify the complete path of where the certificate file is on the machine.

2) Tried different formats of certificates (.pfx; .p12; .cer)

3) Tried the certificate open, read and sent into a buffer to take the input from a buffer. 
(I removed the buffer logic when deploying on IIS7 as I placed the .pfx certificate file in System32 folder and the code could automatically recognise the certificate. But the local would not recognize)

4) I tried removing the   "X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet" parameter. (I use that for the IIS7 compilation)

Any help is appreciated!!

Comment: I advise checking for differences between the application pools on your local machine and the server that throws the exception.

smells like a permission issue...

Answer (score 0):

Thanks! I could figure out what needed.
I had to create an App Pool for the Certificate and then provide Full Control permissions to that pool